# How do I cook toast on an Aga?

Tags: bread

I've an "Aga toaster", which is like a couple of disks of 2cm wire mesh joined together with a handle:

[image: Aga toaster]

But no matter what I try, most of the time the toast sticks. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried non-stick cooking spray?  Olive oil?  Butter?  No difference?

Comment: Have you pre-heated the "Aga toaster"? (Or is it sticking to the plate?)

Comment: I would, but I don't want the butter cooked - fried bread is nice, but it's not what I'm after with my coffee in the morning!

Comment: Yes, pre-heating makes little difference. I think it cools down by the time I've opened the lid and popped the bread in.

Comment: Once you've had a go at the other solution, let me know if you still have problems. I have an Aga expert on tap, but it will take some snail time to get a response. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to tossing some **Flour** on your Aga toaster first, but it will give you extra grill marks on your toast.

Comment: Now that sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a go and report back. Grill marks aren't a problem, it's part of the character of the whole thing -- if I cared that much I'd use an electric toaster, but given that the Aga is warm and ready...

Comment: And yes, did the trick nicely, bravo!

Answer (score 2):

We have found that the best way to cook the toast with our AGA toaster is to open the silver lid and place your AGA toaster with the toast inside on the metal hot pan, but **do not close the lid**. After a while, turn your toast over and lift up the top facing handle of the toaster. Repeat this process for the perfect toast or toasts.

If you want to do this faster, do exactly as I've said but with the lid down and open the lid and toaster lid more frequently.